# Custom Fields - how to get the value of one rendering control in another rendering control?

Tags: 2010, custom-field-types, rendering-template

I am working with some custom fields.  One of them is a choice field.  I need to be able to get the value of the currently selected item in the choice field rendering control (i.e. what would be `FieldRenderingControl.Value`) in the other custom field rendering control.

I know I could probably wrangle some jQuery to hook into the drop-down and get the value every time it changes (although I took a quick stab at that already and was having problems), but I'm OK with having the first field post-back every time because the choices in the second field are going to change depending on the currently selected item in the first field, so a visit to the server is fine.

My current approach is the following - in the OnAdded() method of the second field, I look for the first field and set it as the `SPField.RelatedField` by doing this:

```
public override void OnAdded(SPAddFieldOptions op)
{
    base.OnAdded(op);
    try
    {
        this.RelatedField = this.ParentList.Fields.Cast<SPField>().Where(fld => fld.TypeAsString.Equals("MyFirstCustomFieldType")).Single().InternalName;
        this.Update();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // log the error
    }
}
```

And then in the field rendering control for the second field, I try to get the value from the first field like this:

```
SPField relatedField = this.List.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(this.Field.RelatedField);

string selectedValue = this.ListItem.Fields[relatedField.Id].FieldRenderingControl.Value.ToString();
```

This is not working.  Of particular note is that, following certain patterns I found online (I'm new to custom fields), the `get` of the `FieldRenderingControl` property of the first field returns a *new* field rendering control object, so it's not ever going to find the value of the current field rendering control.

I have also speculated that, if I stored the field ID or Display Name in the `RelatedField` property (instead of the Internal Name), I could get the value in the database of the first field by using `this.ListItem[this.RelatedField]` (casting as GUID if I used ID, of course), however this doesn't help me if it's a new item (with no value in the database), or if the selected item changes in the drop-down but hasn't been submitted yet (and thus hasn't been written to the database yet).

So... any insight as to how I can get the currently selected value of a field rendering control in a different field rendering control, server-side?

EDIT: Ok, so I solved the issues I was having with jQuery and can manage to get the value of the first field rendering control into the second field rendering control while staying client-side, but I'm not sure I like this approach as it makes the two rendering controls too tightly coupled.  Still would like to know if there's a way to do this server-side.